# API for testing on local (dreamweaver)

Tags: google-maps-api-3

Essentially, I'm trying to write my google maps project locally, but I'm just getting these errors.

```
Google has disabled use of the Maps API for this application. The provided key is not a valid Google API Key, or it is not authorized for the Google Maps Javascript API v3 on this site....
```

It seems like the other answers were written for another version of the google API, because I've tried the suggested fixes, and white listing these:

```
*humboldt.edu/* 
*localhost* 
file://* 
http://localhost/*
```

as suggested by previous questions doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a key at all while developing the project or ommit the referers.

The referers are used to prevent the key from abuse, a referer like `localhost/*` wouldn't secure the key, there are a lot of people out there with a "localhost".

When you really need/want to use the key(with referers) you may try to create a virtual host where you run the application and use the virtual host as referer.